# When I try to take the id it takes it as an undefined variable

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

When I try to take the id it takes it as an undefined variable, but if I just do the res.send () there is no problem Well, I can't think of what to do, have I made several attempts during days, any recommendations?

```
router.get('/products/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const idsiguiente = req.params.id + 1;
  const idanterior = req.params.id - 1;

  var numero_de_articulos = 16;
  const iniciar = (id - 1) * numero_de_articulos;

  console.log(req.params.id);
  
  conexion.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS cuenta_productos FROM Products', (error, cuenta_productos) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    
    var paginas = cuenta_productos[0]['cuenta_productos'] / numero_de_articulos;
    paginas = Math.ceil(paginas);

    conexion.query('SELECT * FROM Products limit ?,?', [iniciar, numero_de_articulos], (error, productos) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      //res.send(productos);
      res.render('products', {
        products: productos,
        id: id,
        paginas: 1,
        siguiente: idsiguiente,
        anterior: idanterior
      });
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: I would try `console.log(req.params);` to see all the available fields and see whether `id` is one of them.

Comment: @AlexisWilke How can it be missing when the route is for `/products/:id`? That automatically fills in `req.params.id`.

Comment: Could be possible that you're sending `'undefined'` (string) from your front-end. This could happen if your request tries to parse an undefined variable to string to append into the path. Check the type of req.params.id